# Infinite number of conserved charges for the Sine-Gordon Lagrangian

Tags: conservation-laws, integrable-systems, sine-gordon

I recently came across a paper of Witten that talks about the S-matrix of the supersymmetric non-linear sigma model. In the beginning part of the paper, he mentions that theories like the non-linear sigma model or the sine-gordon theory have an infinite number of conserved charges which come from locally conserved currents. Also, that the sine-gordon theory which is given by

$${L=\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}\varphi \partial^{\mu}\varphi+\frac{m^2}{\beta^2}cos(\beta \varphi)}$$
supposedly has a conserved charge in every representation of the Lorentz group.

I don't understand how this comes about. It would be great if someone could help me with figuring out how to construct higher spin conserved charges.

This is the paper:
https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.17.2134

Comment: This seems relevant: https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.1603

Comment: This is shown in *Takhtadzhyan, L. A., & Faddeev, L. D. (1974). Essentially nonlinear one-dimensional model of classical field theory. Theoretical and Mathematical Physics, 21(2), 1046–1057. doi:10.1007/bf01035551*, by the method that later came to be known as The **algebraic Bethe Ansatz** or **Quantum inverse scattering method**.